# Tomcat security container that allows login with username OR email address

Tags: security, authentication, tomcat, jdbcrealm

Is there a way to configure Tomcat 8.5 or 9 to allow the user to log in with **either** their username **or** their email address?

I am willing to consider using a 3rd party security container if this solves the problem.

Currently using Tomcat JDBC Realm but only with username.  Do not see ways to modify this Realm to allow **either** username **or** email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Combined Realm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/realm-howto.html#CombinedRealm) which allows several authentication mechanisms. In your case, you probably need 2 DataSourceRealm (rather than 2 JDBC Realms) accessing the same table but with different *userNameCol* parameters.

It's interesting to note that you can mix an authentication based on a tier (database, LDAP) and an authentication based on a local file (UserDatabaseRealm). Then you can still log in with an administrator user even when your database is down and all of the application seems dead to the other users. If there are things that don't need the database, you still can work.

Comment: Thank you Eugene.  I finally had time to test this and it works.  A few comments.  It does work with two JDBCRealms (vs 2 DataSourceRealms).  Was unsure why you suggested that, so I tried the JDBC since that is what I was using.

Comment: Also, as would be expected, I had to add the `email` column (and unique key) to the `user_roles` table so the role lookup would work.  This required populating that new field from the email field in the `users` table.  Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @TedCahall Here is one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35732824/7748072) why DataSourceRealm performs better, or [Tomcat 7 doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/realm.html) which says _This could be a bottleneck for applications with high volumes of realm based authentications_ . The doc doesn't mention that anymore, maybe it should be asked on the users mailing list if it's still like that.

Comment: Thanks. That makes total sense.  I looked in the Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 9 docs in the DataSourceRealm section and both versions sill mentioned the point you made: _The JDBC Realm uses a single db connection. This requires that realm based authentication be synchronized, i.e. only one authentication can be done at a time. This could be a bottleneck for applications with high volumes of realm based authentications._

Comment: If your application can get brute-forced, don't forget to have a look at the [LockOutRealm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#LockOutRealm). The [UserDatabaseRealm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#UserDatabaseRealm) often considered as old-school can be useful when the DB would be unreachable if you may allow an (admin) account to be stored on a file.

Comment: Definitely adding in UserDatabaseRealm in case DB issues and I need to get into the REST part of the app.  Easy to do now that I have multiple Realms!  LockOutRealm also really helpful add.  Thanks Eugene!

Comment: You are wellcome @TedCahall.